# Formato factura electronica

Tags: xml, webservice, soapui

Buenas tardes,

Alguien tiene alguna factura electronica en formato XML, esque necesito probar un servicio de la DIAN y me esta arrojando el error que el formato no es correcto.

En la validacion de la factura me salen estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la verdad no entiendo esos errores.

Comment: ¿Para qué país es la factura?

Comment: Hola @PaulaAndrea para la DIAN, Colombia, El servicio es muy parecido al del Sunat. Saludos

Comment: Probaste generando la clase a partir del XSD que esta en la dian, y desde ahí generar el XML, yo lo hice de esa manera para la dian Colombia y funciono bien

Comment: Por favor, no peques mensajes de error como imagen. Pega directamente el texto del error. Lo que queda claro es que hay un error a partir del nodo `Signature`. Sin más información o un ejemplo del XML que envías, no se puede responder. Por favor, lee [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: Aca encuentras una plantilla para la factura y para la firma, ambas probadas y en estado de prodcuccion. https://github.com/DiegoPoveda/dian-plantilla-de-firma-xades

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo esta factura electronica valida, fue generada de productos familia para una empresa, este es el XML de la factura:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fe:Invoice xmlns:fe="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:clm54217="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:54217:2001" xmlns:clm66411="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:66411:2001" xmlns:clmIANAMIMEMediaType="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:IANAMIMEMediaType:2003" xmlns:cts="urn:carvajal:names:specification:ubl:colombia:schema:xsd:CarvajalAggregateComponents-1" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:sts="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/Structures" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1 ../xsd/DIAN_UBL.xsd urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2 ../../ubl2/common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2 ../../ubl2/common/UBL-QualifiedDatatypes-2.0.xsd">
<ext:UBLExtensions>
<ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:ExtensionContent>
<sts:DianExtensions>
<sts:InvoiceControl>
<sts:InvoiceAuthorization>18762116654443</sts:InvoiceAuthorization><sts:AuthorizationPeriod><cbc:StartDate>2018-01-29</cbc:StartDate><cbc:EndDate>2019-01-29</cbc:EndDate></sts:AuthorizationPeriod><sts:AuthorizedInvoices><sts:Prefix>12</sts:Prefix><sts:From>4110001</sts:From><sts:To>5000000</sts:To></sts:AuthorizedInvoices>
</sts:InvoiceControl>
<sts:InvoiceSource><cbc:IdentificationCode listAgencyID="6" listAgencyName="United Nations Economic Commission for Europe" listSchemeURI="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:codelist:gc:CountryIdentificationCode-2.0">CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
</sts:InvoiceSource>
<sts:SoftwareProvider><sts:ProviderID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">890321151</sts:ProviderID><sts:SoftwareID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">9647c6c3-3185-4f8e-80ff-586a2fd5c050</sts:SoftwareID>
</sts:SoftwareProvider>
<sts:SoftwareSecurityCode schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)"><!--REMOVED--></sts:SoftwareSecurityCode>
</sts:DianExtensions>
</ext:ExtensionContent>
</ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:ExtensionContent><cts:AdditionalDocumentInformation><cts:Header><cts:Copies>1</cts:Copies><cts:PDFTemplate>FLIA01</cts:PDFTemplate><cts:DocumentType>INVOIC</cts:DocumentType><cts:DocumentDueDate>2018-07-12</cts:DocumentDueDate><cts:AccountingSupplierParty><cts:Party><cts:PartyIdentificationID>893330161</cts:PartyIdentificationID></cts:Party></cts:AccountingSupplierParty><cts:AccountingCustomerParty><cts:Party><cts:PartyIdentificationID>933313346</cts:PartyIdentificationID></cts:Party></cts:AccountingCustomerParty><cts:SellerSupplierParty><cts:Party><cts:PartyIdentificationID>899900161</cts:PartyIdentificationID></cts:Party></cts:SellerSupplierParty><cts:BuyerCustomerParty><cts:Party><cts:PartyIdentificationID>933313346</cts:PartyIdentificationID></cts:Party></cts:BuyerCustomerParty></cts:Header><cts:Items><cts:Item><cts:LineNumber>231</cts:LineNumber><cts:ItemPayableAmount currencyID="COP">274723</cts:ItemPayableAmount></cts:Item><cts:Item><cts:LineNumber>233</cts:LineNumber><cts:ItemPayableAmount currencyID="COP">1207017</cts:ItemPayableAmount></cts:Item><cts:Item><cts:LineNumber>235</cts:LineNumber><cts:ItemPayableAmount currencyID="COP">9309195</cts:ItemPayableAmount></cts:Item><cts:Item><cts:LineNumber>301</cts:LineNumber><cts:ItemPayableAmount currencyID="COP">654762</cts:ItemPayableAmount></cts:Item></cts:Items></cts:AdditionalDocumentInformation></ext:ExtensionContent>
</ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:ExtensionContent>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-d03d8240-cf28-4157-b534-d4b241d7ae8f">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-d03d8240-cf28-4157-b534-d4b241d7ae8f-ref0" URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>3ujSLJKLD1+xtw6Un/M9iZ9he6A=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#xmldsig-d03d8240-cf28-4157-b534-d4b241d7ae8f-keyinfo">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>NvF8TWMqSZtvAtZ1A3cc8ulImvw=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-d03d8240-cf28-4157-b534-d4b241d7ae8f-signedprops">
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>/ECR+N2B82s/OD/GEocNAiiSTws=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-d03d8240-cf28-4157-b534-d4b241d7ae8f-sigvalue">
<!--REMOVED-->
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="xmldsig-d03d8240-cf28-4157-b534-d4b241d7ae8f-keyinfo">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
<!--REMOVED-->
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Target="#xmldsig-d03d8240-cf28-4157-b534-d4b241d7ae8f"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-d03d8240-cf28-4157-b534-d4b241d7ae8f-signedprops"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2018-05-28T20:17:23.239-05:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>jPzzA0lf6uPma1yAIEFVXmdXw9M=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>C=CO,L=Bogota D.C.,O=Andes SCD.,OU=Division de certificacion entidad final,CN=CA ANDES SCD S.A. Clase II,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1614696e66000000000d2e636f</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>2111111111111116</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>ydBrkDUi4OLwpDJACttO8PSuHdE=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>C=CO,L=Bogota D.C.,O=Andes SCD,OU=Division de certificacion,CN=ROOT CA ANDES SCD S.A.,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1614696e00000000000042e636f6d2e636f</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>81300000000090815624</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>OXeITae4OgBq7RWNUGqshhvKGk8=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>C=CO,L=Bogota D.C.,O=Andes SCD,OU=Division de certificacion,CN=ROOT CA ANDES SCD S.A.,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1614696e666f0000000000000000006d2e636f</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>3184000000000000000002</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier><xades:SignaturePolicyId><xades:SigPolicyId><xades:Identifier>https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/politicadefirma/v1/politicadefirmav1.pdf</xades:Identifier></xades:SigPolicyId><xades:SigPolicyHash><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>61fInBICBQOCBwuTwlaOZSi9HKc=</ds:DigestValue></xades:SigPolicyHash></xades:SignaturePolicyId></xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier><xades:SignerRole><xades:ClaimedRoles><xades:ClaimedRole>supplier</xades:ClaimedRole></xades:ClaimedRoles></xades:SignerRole></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties>
</ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
</ext:ExtensionContent>
</ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>
<cbc:UBLVersionID>UBL 2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:ProfileID>DIAN 1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
<cbc:ID>124063277</cbc:ID>
<cbc:UUID schemeName="CUFE"><!--REMOVED--></cbc:UUID>
<cbc:IssueDate>2018-05-28</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:IssueTime>20:17:19</cbc:IssueTime>
<cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listAgencyID="195" listAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" listSchemeURI="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/InvoiceType">1</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
<cbc:Note>1_</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>2_BOGOTA  212 57 00    CALI    664 21 27 |MEDELLIN 360 96 00   RESTO DEL PAIS 18000520033 |CORREO ELECTRONICO servicioalclientecol@familia.com.co</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>3_SEÑOR TRANSPORTADOR: VERIFIQUE EL CARGUE EN CANTIDAD Y CALIDAD PARA EVITAR RECLAMACIONES EN LAS ENTREGAS. PARA LA CANCELACION DE FLETES ES INDISPENSABLE DEVOLVER UNA COPIA FIRMADA.|PRODUCTOS FAMILIA NO SE HACERESPONSABLE POR LOS FALTANTES O AVERIAS. ESTE DOCUMENTO TIENE CARACTER DE CONTRATO DE TRANSPORTE. SU FIRMA IMPLICA RESPONSABILIDAD DEL CARGAMENTO QUE EN ELLA SE DETALLA.</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>4_EL CLIENTE ACEPTA QUE LA PERSONA QUE FIRMA EL PRESENTE DOCUMENTO TIENE AUTORIZACION PARA RECIBIR Y POR LO TANTO EN ESTE ACTO ES REPRESENTANTE DEL CLIENTE Y SE HACE RESPONSABLE DE SU CANCELACION</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>5_AUTORIZACIÓN NUMERACIÓN DE FACTURACIÓN FORMULARIO 18762006654443 DEL 20180129. PREFIJO 12 DEL 4000001 AL 5000000.  VIGENCIA 12 MESES.|SOMOSAUTORRETENEDORES RENTA SEGÚN RESOLUCIÓN 001250 DEL 20140220 Y DECRETO2201 DE 20161230. SOMOS GRANDES CONTRIBUYENTES SEGÚN RESOLUCIÓN 076 DEL 20161201. SOMOS AGENTES RETENEDORES DEL IMPUESTO A LAS VENTAS (IVA)POR LEY 233 DEL 19981220|LA NO CANCELACIÓN DE ESTA FACTURA EN SU VENCIMIENTO CAUSARÁ EL INTERES MÁXIMO LEGAL VIGENTE. LAS DEDUCCIONES Y LOSFALTANTES DE</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>5_BEN SER REGISTRADOS EN ESTA FACTURA AL MOMENTO DEL RECIBO.NO SE ACEPTAN RECLAMOS POSTERIORES A LA FIRMA DE LA FACTURA.</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>6_0124063277</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>7_000  Normal Ventas</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>8_900313346</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>9_17125</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>10_2431091-2432084</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>11_VENTAS A CREDITO</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>12_</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>13_10661280</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>14_0124063277</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>15_</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>16_</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>17_10661280</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>18_10661280</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>19_FACTURA DE VENTA</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>20_</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>21_124063277</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>22_3280|190</cbc:Note><cbc:Note>NumFac: 124063277 FecFac: 20180528201719 ValFac: 10661280.00 CodImp1: 01 ValImp1: 784417.00 CodImp2: 02 ValImp2: 0.00 CodImp3: 03 ValImp3: 0.00 ValImp: 11445697.00 NitOFE: 890900161 TipAdq: 31 NumAdq: 900313346 String: 1240632772018052820171910661280.0001784417.00020.00030.0011445697.00890900161319003133467d8e8b6f4000000000000000000d3e3e0c9bef6e52f7bac5</cbc:Note><cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>COP</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode><cbc:LineCountNumeric>4</cbc:LineCountNumeric><cac:OrderReference><cbc:ID>629</cbc:ID><cbc:SalesOrderID>0044160540</cbc:SalesOrderID><cbc:IssueDate>2018-05-23</cbc:IssueDate></cac:OrderReference><fe:AccountingSupplierParty><cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID><fe:Party><cac:PartyIdentification><cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="31">890900161</cbc:ID></cac:PartyIdentification><cac:PartyName><cbc:Name>PRODUCTOS FAMILIA S.A.</cbc:Name></cac:PartyName><fe:PhysicalLocation><cbc:Description>Carrera XX No. X sur-117</cbc:Description><fe:Address><cbc:Department>ANTIOQUIA</cbc:Department><cbc:CitySubdivisionName>Medellín</cbc:CitySubdivisionName><cbc:CityName>Medellín</cbc:CityName><cac:AddressLine><cbc:Line>Carrera 50 No. 8 sur-117</cbc:Line></cac:AddressLine><cac:Country><cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode></cac:Country></fe:Address></fe:PhysicalLocation><fe:PartyTaxScheme><cbc:TaxLevelCode>2</cbc:TaxLevelCode><cac:TaxScheme/></fe:PartyTaxScheme><fe:PartyLegalEntity><cbc:RegistrationName>PRODUCTOS FAMILIA S.A.</cbc:RegistrationName></fe:PartyLegalEntity><cac:Contact><cbc:Name>JUAN FERNANDO ZULUAGA</cbc:Name><cbc:Telephone>(574)360 9500</cbc:Telephone><cbc:ElectronicMail>juanzr@familia.com.co</cbc:ElectronicMail></cac:Contact></fe:Party></fe:AccountingSupplierParty><fe:AccountingCustomerParty><cbc:SupplierAssignedAccountID>10000</cbc:SupplierAssignedAccountID><cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID><fe:Party><cac:PartyIdentification><cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="31">9000003346</cbc:ID></cac:PartyIdentification><cac:PartyName><cbc:Name>XXXXXXX XXXXX SAS </cbc:Name></cac:PartyName><fe:PhysicalLocation><cbc:Description>AV XXXXX 00B 10 14</cbc:Description><fe:Address><cbc:Department/><cbc:CitySubdivisionName>CALI</cbc:CitySubdivisionName><cbc:CityName>CALI</cbc:CityName><cac:AddressLine><cbc:Line>AV XXXXX XXXX 00B 10 14</cbc:Line></cac:AddressLine><cac:Country><cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode></cac:Country></fe:Address></fe:PhysicalLocation><fe:PartyTaxScheme><cbc:TaxLevelCode>2</cbc:TaxLevelCode><cac:TaxScheme/></fe:PartyTaxScheme><fe:PartyLegalEntity><cbc:RegistrationName>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX </cbc:RegistrationName></fe:PartyLegalEntity><cac:Contact><cbc:Name>Buzon Factura Electronica</cbc:Name><cbc:Telephone>24000001-240000004</cbc:Telephone><cbc:ElectronicMail>dXXXXXXXXs@hotmail.com;</cbc:ElectronicMail></cac:Contact></fe:Party></fe:AccountingCustomerParty><cac:BuyerCustomerParty><cbc:AdditionalAccountID>10000</cbc:AdditionalAccountID><cac:Party><cac:PartyIdentification><cbc:ID schemeID="31">900313346</cbc:ID></cac:PartyIdentification><cac:PartyName><cbc:Name>XXXXXXXXXX SAS</cbc:Name></cac:PartyName><cac:PhysicalLocation><cbc:Description>AV XXXXXXXXB 10 14</cbc:Description><cac:Address><cbc:CitySubdivisionName>CALI</cbc:CitySubdivisionName><cbc:CityName>CALI</cbc:CityName><cac:AddressLine><cbc:Line>AV XXXXXXXXXXB 10 14</cbc:Line></cac:AddressLine><cac:Country><cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode></cac:Country></cac:Address></cac:PhysicalLocation><cac:PartyTaxScheme><cbc:TaxLevelCode>2</cbc:TaxLevelCode><cac:TaxScheme/></cac:PartyTaxScheme><cac:PartyLegalEntity><cbc:RegistrationName>XXXXXXXXX SAS</cbc:RegistrationName></cac:PartyLegalEntity><cac:Person><cbc:FirstName>XXXXXXXXXXX SAS</cbc:FirstName><cbc:FamilyName>XXXXXXXXXXX SAS</cbc:FamilyName></cac:Person></cac:Party></cac:BuyerCustomerParty><cac:SellerSupplierParty><cac:Party><cac:PartyIdentification><cbc:ID schemeID="31">89000000001</cbc:ID></cac:PartyIdentification><cac:PartyName><cbc:Name>PRODUCTOS FAMILIA S.A.</cbc:Name></cac:PartyName><cac:PhysicalLocation><cbc:Description>Carrera XX No. X sur-117</cbc:Description><cac:Address><cbc:Department>ANTIOQUIA</cbc:Department><cbc:CitySubdivisionName>Medellín</cbc:CitySubdivisionName><cbc:CityName>Medellín</cbc:CityName><cac:AddressLine><cbc:Line>Carrera XX No. X sur-117</cbc:Line></cac:AddressLine><cac:Country><cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode></cac:Country></cac:Address></cac:PhysicalLocation><cac:PartyTaxScheme><cbc:TaxLevelCode>2</cbc:TaxLevelCode><cac:TaxScheme/></cac:PartyTaxScheme><cac:PartyLegalEntity><cbc:RegistrationName>PRODUCTOS FAMILIA S.A.</cbc:RegistrationName></cac:PartyLegalEntity></cac:Party></cac:SellerSupplierParty><fe:Delivery><cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2018-05-28</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate><fe:DeliveryLocation><cbc:Description>AV SIMON BOLIVAR 33B 10 14</cbc:Description><fe:Address><cbc:CitySubdivisionName>CALI</cbc:CitySubdivisionName><cbc:CityName>CALI</cbc:CityName><cac:AddressLine><cbc:Line>XXXXXXXXXXX SAS</cbc:Line></cac:AddressLine><cac:Country><cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode></cac:Country></fe:Address></fe:DeliveryLocation><fe:Despatch><cbc:ActualDespatchDate>2018-05-28</cbc:ActualDespatchDate></fe:Despatch></fe:Delivery><fe:TaxTotal><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">784417</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator><fe:TaxSubtotal><cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">1245160</cbc:TaxableAmount><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">236580</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:Percent>19</cbc:Percent><cac:TaxCategory><cac:TaxScheme><cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID><cbc:TaxTypeCode>01</cbc:TaxTypeCode></cac:TaxScheme></cac:TaxCategory></fe:TaxSubtotal><fe:TaxSubtotal><cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">9416120</cbc:TaxableAmount><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">547837</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:Percent>5</cbc:Percent><cac:TaxCategory><cac:TaxScheme><cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID><cbc:TaxTypeCode>01</cbc:TaxTypeCode></cac:TaxScheme></cac:TaxCategory></fe:TaxSubtotal></fe:TaxTotal><fe:LegalMonetaryTotal><cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">10661280</cbc:LineExtensionAmount><cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="COP">10661280</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount><cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="COP">11445697</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount><cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="COP">0</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount><cbc:ChargeTotalAmount currencyID="COP">0</cbc:ChargeTotalAmount><cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="COP">11445697</cbc:PayableAmount></fe:LegalMonetaryTotal>
<fe:InvoiceLine><cbc:ID>231</cbc:ID><cbc:Note>629</cbc:Note><cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="CS">20</cbc:InvoicedQuantity><cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">230860</cbc:LineExtensionAmount><cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>true</cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator><cac:PricingReference/><cac:TaxTotal><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">43863</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator><cac:TaxSubtotal><cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">230860</cbc:TaxableAmount><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">43863</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:Percent>19</cbc:Percent><cac:TaxCategory><cac:TaxScheme><cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID><cbc:TaxTypeCode>01</cbc:TaxTypeCode></cac:TaxScheme></cac:TaxCategory></cac:TaxSubtotal></cac:TaxTotal><fe:Item><cbc:Description>PQ-CS|TOAL.COCI. ACOLCHAMAX DECORADA 40HJ. 6X1</cbc:Description><cbc:PackQuantity unitCode="PA">120</cbc:PackQuantity><cac:SellersItemIdentification><cbc:ID>62237</cbc:ID></cac:SellersItemIdentification><cac:StandardItemIdentification><cbc:ID>7702026622336</cbc:ID></cac:StandardItemIdentification></fe:Item><fe:Price><cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">11543</cbc:PriceAmount></fe:Price>
</fe:InvoiceLine>
<fe:InvoiceLine><cbc:ID>233</cbc:ID><cbc:Note>629</cbc:Note><cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="CS">60</cbc:InvoicedQuantity><cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">1014300</cbc:LineExtensionAmount><cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>true</cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator><cac:PricingReference/><cac:TaxTotal><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">192717</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator><cac:TaxSubtotal><cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">1014300</cbc:TaxableAmount><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">192717</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:Percent>19</cbc:Percent><cac:TaxCategory><cac:TaxScheme><cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID><cbc:TaxTypeCode>01</cbc:TaxTypeCode></cac:TaxScheme></cac:TaxCategory></cac:TaxSubtotal></cac:TaxTotal><fe:Item><cbc:Description>PQ-CS|PAPEL HIG. ACMAX GRANDE 2PQX12R 22M</cbc:Description><cbc:PackQuantity unitCode="PA">120</cbc:PackQuantity><cac:SellersItemIdentification><cbc:ID>11303</cbc:ID></cac:SellersItemIdentification><cac:StandardItemIdentification><cbc:ID>7702026175290</cbc:ID></cac:StandardItemIdentification></fe:Item><fe:Price><cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">16905</cbc:PriceAmount></fe:Price>
</fe:InvoiceLine>
<fe:InvoiceLine><cbc:ID>235</cbc:ID><cbc:Note>629</cbc:Note><cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="CS">100</cbc:InvoicedQuantity><cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">8865900</cbc:LineExtensionAmount><cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>true</cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator><cac:PricingReference/><cac:TaxTotal><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">443295</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator><cac:TaxSubtotal><cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">8865900</cbc:TaxableAmount><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">443295</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:Percent>5</cbc:Percent><cac:TaxCategory><cac:TaxScheme><cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID><cbc:TaxTypeCode>01</cbc:TaxTypeCode></cac:TaxScheme></cac:TaxCategory></cac:TaxSubtotal></cac:TaxTotal><fe:Item><cbc:Description>PQ-CS|TOAL.PLUS CANALGEL 30(10Y5NDMULTIESTILO)</cbc:Description><cbc:PackQuantity unitCode="PA">3000</cbc:PackQuantity><cac:SellersItemIdentification><cbc:ID>44481</cbc:ID></cac:SellersItemIdentification><cac:StandardItemIdentification><cbc:ID>7702027444814</cbc:ID></cac:StandardItemIdentification></fe:Item><fe:Price><cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">88659</cbc:PriceAmount></fe:Price>
</fe:InvoiceLine>
<fe:InvoiceLine><cbc:ID>301</cbc:ID><cbc:Note>629</cbc:Note><cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="CS">10</cbc:InvoicedQuantity><cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">550220</cbc:LineExtensionAmount><cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>true</cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator><cac:PricingReference/><cac:TaxTotal><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">104542</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator><cac:TaxSubtotal><cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">550220</cbc:TaxableAmount><cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">104542</cbc:TaxAmount><cbc:Percent>19</cbc:Percent><cac:TaxCategory><cac:TaxScheme><cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID><cbc:TaxTypeCode>01</cbc:TaxTypeCode></cac:TaxScheme></cac:TaxCategory></cac:TaxSubtotal></cac:TaxTotal><fe:Item><cbc:Description>PQ-CS|TOALLI. HUM. ACOLCHAMAX 4X(160Y40)</cbc:Description><cbc:PackQuantity unitCode="PA">40</cbc:PackQuantity><cac:SellersItemIdentification><cbc:ID>31761</cbc:ID></cac:SellersItemIdentification><cac:StandardItemIdentification><cbc:ID>7702026340292</cbc:ID></cac:StandardItemIdentification></fe:Item><fe:Price><cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">55022</cbc:PriceAmount></fe:Price>
</fe:InvoiceLine>
</fe:Invoice>
```

Me ha servido mucho para generar la mia, espero te ayude.

Suerte.